# Counting raster points within boundaries in another layer?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, export

I know this question is similar to some out there, but I have tried all the 'solutions' and none of them are working for me. 
I am using the latest version of Qgis.

I have a raster layer with lat/long/ARI attributes (average recurrence intervals)
I have a vector layer with country boundaries

I want to count/collect all the raster points within each country and then export this data in to a text file so I can then calculate min/max/mean values of ARI within each country.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work for you? What do you mean with "raster points"? There are only vector points or raster cells.

Comment: raster "points"? Do you have a xyz-data layer or is it just a normal grid? Etherway have a look at zonal-statistics

Answer (score 2):

An easier option is to use zonal statistics. This allows you to get stats (min, max, mean, etc) of raster cells under a polygon. Make sure your polygon has a unique attribute in the table. Look at this site for further info: http://gis-lab.info/qa/zonalstats-qgis-eng.html

Answer (score 1):

Convert your raster cells to points (assuming that the "raster points" are single cells). Then it's a very simple spatial query of points within a region.

I would install [SAGA GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html) & use the QGIS Processing framework to access SAGA:

1. Load raster with ARI data
2. SAGA - Shapes - Grid

   1. Grid Values to Points
3. Use QGIS Spatial Query toolbar to perform your spatial intersection